# Find missing foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Okay, this one is an easy one I think.  I have a one to many relationship between `tblWorkouts` and `tblPersonalRecords`.  I've now deleted some rows from `tblWorkouts` without deleting them from `tblPersonalRecords` (I should have setup a foreign key and a cascade delete...).

I'm trying to figure out a query to find the orphaned rows in `tblPersonalRecords`.  Here's what I tried:

```
from s in db.tblPersonalRecords
where s.tblWorkoutRecord.WorkoutSummaryID == null
select s
```

That doesn't work.  How do I write a LINQ query to find my orphaned rows?  I'm using Linq2Sql if that makes a difference.

Comment: I assume that you've checked the database, and those columns are null?

Comment: It's not that the column is null, it's that there is not a corresponding row in the tblworkoutRecord database.  I tried doing s.tblworkoutrecord == null, but it didn't like that syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
var result = from s in db.tblPersonalRecords
                         join j in db.tblWorkoutRecords on s.WorkoutRecordID equals j.WorkoutRecordID into PersonalWorkout
                         from j in PersonalWorkout.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where j == null
                         select new
                         {
                             PersonalRecordID = s.PersonalRecordID,
                             WorkoutRecordIDPR = s.WorkoutRecordID,
                             WorkoutRecordID = j == null ? 0 : 1
                         };
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading your comment on the question you probably want:

```
from s in db.tblPersonalRecords
where !db.PersonalWorkout.Any(x => s.WorkoutRecordID == x.WorkoutRecordID)
select s
```

Comment: @Nate !db.PersonalWorkout.Any( should be !s.PersonalWorkouts.Any( Provided you have relationship properly created

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I misunderstand the question but why would you check if the value in tblPersonalRecords is null when you have not updated the rows at all after deleting rows from tblWorkouts ?

I would expect the would-be foreign key values to now point to rows that don't exist anymore in tblWorkouts rather than being null.

If that's the case then maybe something like this would help:

```
var ids = from w in db.tblWorkouts
          select w.id;

var rows = from s in db.tblPersonalRecords
           where !ids.Contains(s.tblWorkoutRecord.WorkoutSummaryID)
           select s;
```

What is it that the compiler is complaining about in case of your original statement anyway ? What type of error are you getting?